# How to get from factorial to a y-combinator?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming, factorial

In one of his conference talks Jim Weirich derives the applicative form of the y-combinator by refactoring a partial definition of factorial. The starting point in his talk is different than what follows here but the ideas are all the same.

Let's start with the following function

```
# partial definition of factorial
f = \g -> \x -> x == 1 ? 1 : x * g(g)(x - 1)
# factorial = f(f)
```

Notice that we never name something simultaneously on the LHS and the RHS, i.e. there is no recursion. With the above starting point getting to a y-combinator is pretty simple

```
# first factor out g(g)(x - 1)
\g -> (\h -> \x -> x == 1 ? 1 : x * h(x - 1))(\y -> g(g)(y))
# next factor out \h -> \x -> ...
(\f -> \g -> f(\y -> g(g)(y)))(\h -> \x -> x == 1 ? 1 : x * h(x - 1))
```

Now if you look at the function that is being applied to the partial definition of factorial

```
\f -> \g -> f(\y -> g(g)(y))
```

we just need to apply it to itself after applying it to a partial definition of factorial to get the full factorial. Spelling that out with lambdas gives us

```
y = \p -> (\h -> h(h))((\f -> \g -> f(\y -> g(g)(y))(p))
```

It is still pretty incomprehensible standing on its own but deriving it from the partial definition of factorial makes sense to me. One problem I have with it though is that you somehow have to guess the expression `g(g)` and it is not at all clear why. Let's say we start with the recursive definition of factorial

```
factorial = \x -> x == 1 ? 1 : x * factorial(x - 1)
```

The obvious thing to do if you can't refer to the name of the function within the body of the function is to try to abstract it

```
factorial = (\g -> \x -> x == 1 ? 1 : x * g(x - 1))(factorial)
```

The problem is that this is a dead end. I don't see how you can guess that the right thing to do is to factor `g(x - 1)` into `g(g)(x - 1)` and start the chain of reasoning at the top of this post. In his talk Jim Weirich does the equivalent of what I did by basically pulling `g(g)` out of a hat.

So the question is does anyone know a motivating reason for why the proper placeholder in the partial definition of factorial is `g(g)(x - 1)`?

Comment: See also [this answer to Clear, intuitive derivation of the fixed-point combinator (Y combinator)?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9651/2448).

Comment: @PetrPudlák Thanks, that's a really good answer and gives a pretty good heuristic for how `g(g)` comes about from informal reasoning about the recursive definitions.